# Oblique asymptote of exponential

Tags: curves

How do I derive the oblique asymptote for
$$y = \frac{x+2}{e^x - 2}$$

In case it's needed, the supposed answer is $$ y = -0.5x - 1$$

Comment: Find slope with $\lim_\infty\dfrac{y}{x}$ first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Just find the slop
$$m=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\dfrac{y}{x}$$
which gives $m=-\dfrac12$ as $x\to-\infty$ and then find 
$$h=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}y-mx=-1$$

Comment: Hello, do you mind explaining what value of y did you use?

To me, as x approaches $-\infty$, 
$$y \to \frac{e^(-\infty)}{-\infty} \to 0$$.

Comment: @OngHaiXiang As $x\to+\infty$, $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\dfrac{y}{x}\to0$and doesn't make oblique asymptote.

Answer (score 1):

Your function has no an oblique asymptote because
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x+2}{e^x-2}=0$$ and 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{x+2}{e^x-2}=+\infty$$